# NSDateFormatter not behaving properly when converting from Buddhist calendar to Gregorian calendar date formats

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm making an app that supports conversion of dates from the Buddhist calendar to Gregorian (Note: The "General > International > Calendar" settings of the device I'm testing on is "Buddhist".).  However, I can't figure out why the NSDateFormatter doesn't parse my dates properly. Here's my code:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.calendar = gregorianCalendar;
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";

NSString *formattedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
NSDate *boomDate = [formatter dateFromString:formattedDate];

NSLog(@"now: %@, formattedDate (as string) > %@, boomDate (as date) > %@", now, formattedDate, boomDate);
```

Xcode's log says:

```
now: 2556-05-23 07:11:03 +0000, formattedDate (as string) > 2013-05-23 15:11:03 +0800, boomDate (as date) > 2556-05-23 07:11:03 +0000
```

When I'm converting the `formattedDate` (which is an NSString) to an NSDate, why does my NSDateFormatter parse it according to the Buddhist calendar format even if I set it's properties properly (especially the `formatter.calendar`). I need my `formattedDate` converted as an NSDate with the Gregorian calendar format. Based on its logic, I'm expecting the NSDateFormatter to give me a date with the Gregorian format but it doesn't.

Basically, I need an NSDate following the Gregorian format from a Buddhist NSDate.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe this where your issue is `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +HHMM";` change it to `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"`

Comment: It doesn't seem like it is. I changed it but the year of `boomDate` still follows the Buddhist year.

Comment: What are you trying to do with boomDate, creating the original Buddhist date from the formattedDate?

Comment: Nope. I want the Buddhist date converted to Gregorian date. I'm creating a new NSDate from the Buddhist date converted to the Gregorian format.

Comment: Can you update the log in your question, it is still from your original dateFormat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30465/discussion-between-anupdas-and-acecapades)

Comment: @acecapades : what is the time zone of buddhist year ... change that in gregorian properly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDate` is just an object wrapper for a double value indicating the offset from the reference date. It does not contain information about calendars or timezones. It's just a point in time.

What we as humans decide to call this point in time depends on our calendar and timezone. An NSDate object has no meaning without a calendar and timezone.

When you're printing a date object using `NSLog`, the `-description` method on your date object gets called, and the `-description` method formats the string using your device's locale. That's why the `boomDate` is shown with buddhist calendar properties; your buddhist locale uses a buddhist calendar.

The `now` and `boomDate` variables are equal (try calling `[now isEqualToDate:boomDate]`).

You can tell that the conversion to gregorian succeeded, because the `formattedDate` shows the date as it would be in the gregorian calendar.